# Properly converting JSON to string

Tags: json, go

I am writing a function in which I am getting data in JSON format. I want to convert this JSON into string format then write in log file. Below is my code:

```
func JSONToString(logs map[string]interface{}){
    jsonLog, err := json.Marshal(logs)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    jsonLogString := string(jsonLog[:len(jsonLog)])
    logfile := "/ServiceLogs/" + "UploadServiceLog_" + currentTime.Format("2006-01-02") + ".txt"
    jsonLogFile, err := os.OpenFile(logfile, os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    defer jsonLogFile.Close()

    jsonLogFile.WriteString(jsonLogString + "\n")
    jsonLogFile.Close()
}
```

Now what I get in logs is like

> {"Errors":{},"RequestEnd":1569214715575873000,"ResponseTime":1569214715575.873,"ServiceName":"IMAGE_LISTING_SERVICE","Times":{"BasicValidationTime":0.150016,"ExtraValidationTime":0.002048,"FormParsingTime":0.479232,"ImagePgConnectionTime":0.31488,"RequestDecodingTime":0.009216}}

But I actually wanted this:

> "{\"Errors\":{},\"RequestEnd\":1569214715575873000,\"ResponseTime\":1569214715575.873,\"ServiceName\":\"IMAGE_LISTING_SERVICE\",\"Times\":{\"BasicValidationTime\":0.150016,\"ExtraValidationTime\":0.002048,\"FormParsingTime\":0.479232,\"ImagePgConnectionTime\":0.31488,\"RequestDecodingTime\":0.009216}}"

I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: If you want a JSON string, which contains an escaped JSON object, just marshal it twice. But... why do you want that?

Comment: `strconv.Quote(somestring)`.

Comment: @Filmzy I want to convert this in string because I am applying elastic search on this data. And I dont want to apply my search for all these keys. So for some keys I will just keep everything as a string and assign everything as a string to one key. And rest of the keys, I will include them in my elastic search. If these fields are written as it is then it will also be included in my elastic search any I dont want that.